# How to save an org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] of 46 tuples to cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I have a data with 46 field and I converted it into data frame in spark. After it coveted into RDD of **usersTable**: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]. Now I want to save this file to Cassandra but getting below error:

error: object Tuple46 is not a member of package scala

I have tried:

```
val usersTable = sqlContext.sql("select a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, aa, ab, ac, ad, ae, af, ag, ah, ai, aj, ak, al, am, an, ao, ap, aq, ar, as, at from abcdef").rdd

usersTable: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[39] at rdd at <console>:67

val finalUsers = usersTable.flatMap(e => (e(0).toString, e(1).toString, e(2).toString, e(3).toString, e(4).toString, e(5).toString, e(6).toString, e(7).toString, e(8).toString, e(9).toString, e(10).toString, e(11).toString, e(12).toString, e(13).toString, e(14).toString, e(15).toString, e(16).toString, e(17).toString, e(18).toString, e(19).toString, e(20).toString, e(21).toString, e(22).toString, e(23).toString, e(24).toString, e(25).toString, e(26).toString, e(27).toString, e(28).toString, e(29).toString, e(30).toString, e(31).toString, e(32).toString, e(33).toString, e(34).toString, e(35).toString, e(36).toString, e(37).toString, e(38).toString, e(39).toString, e(40).toString, e(41).toString, e(42).toString, e(43).toString, e(44).toString, e(45).toString))

error: object Tuple46 is not a member of package scala
```

what is the possible way to save large column table in Cassandra?

Comment: Scala has an upper limit of 22 on Tuples, but you can make your own implementation if you want. However, I am wondering if it is even necessary for you to map your rows to tuples - I would imagine that the Cassandra connector can process Rows. I don't use Cassandra myself, so I don't know, but I write everything to parquet files and writing to parquet requires the format to be in Rows...

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I know about the tuples limit in Scala. I think if you can give me any reference to increase tuples limit that will be helpful for me or you can suggest me alternative way except parquet because at the end I have to save data into Cassandra only.